# HTML5+JS canvas unexpected line style

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

As I get from previous experience and documentation online, the following code should produce two vertical lines, one red and the other green.

Instead, I get two green lines or whatever `strokeStyle` I set at last.

I can't see where this code is wrong. Furthermore, it may be my browser that somehow boggles things up.

The [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j4gjk035/) and the code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <canvas></canvas>
    <script>

      var cvs = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
      var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

      ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
      ctx.moveTo(1, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(1, 10);
      ctx.stroke();

      ctx.strokeStyle = "#00ff00";
      ctx.moveTo(11, 0);
      ctx.lineTo(11, 10);
      ctx.stroke();

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `closePath()` after your first line and before the second one.

Note that it will return you to your starting point.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/closePath

EDIT:

I'd made an assumption that both paths had been begun as the OP described the lines being the same colour rather than not drawing at all.

Interestingly in a small local test the lines do draw without any begin paths, but the first line is drawn twice with the colour from the intended second path.

The correct answer is to `beginPath()` and `closePath()` each time as shown below:

```
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#ff0000";
  ctx.moveTo(1, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(1, 10);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.strokeStyle = "#00ff00";
  ctx.moveTo(11, 0);
  ctx.lineTo(11, 10);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.closePath();
```

Comment: You will need a beginPath if you intend to draw several paths.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ctx.beginPath()` when you start your new line (this will implicitly close your previous path).

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j4gjk035/1/).

Comment: Thanks to both of you, this solved the problem. I accepted dougajmcdonald's answer because he was quicker and sent a link to the docs. But your answer worked well, to. I'd accept both if I could.

Comment: @pid That's fine, but he wasn't actually quicker (look at the timestamps).

Comment: Your last sentence is not correct. beginPath will not close the previous path, only closePath will. But yes, beginPath is required if you intend to draw more than one path.